# Open Visual Lightbox with CSS button

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, href

Yesterday, I asked a question related to Fancybox and someone was uber-helpful in showing me the piece I was missing.  Now that I figured all that out, though, I realized....Fancybox just wasn't what I wanted.  I've decided to go with Visual Lightbox (v5.0), instead, because it is more obvious to basic page viewers what to do with the controls once it is opened.

Having said that, I have used the information I learned yesterday to get everything working perfect - multiple galleries, integrated thumbnail launch, etc - it all works perfect!  What I NOW want to do is be able to launch each thumbnail's unique lightbox gallery from a CSS button.  I have read dozens of questions that seem to relate but none of the tricks I've read through are working for mine.

So here we go.  The CSS for the button:

```
    <style type="text/css">
a.bigbutton {   
    style="border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: normal;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 1px #3f3f3f;
    width:100%;
    height:32px;
    padding-top:6px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff !important;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#2b2b2b;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

The HTML for the button as it stands right now:

```
    <a href="album-detail.html" class="bigbutton">VIEW PHOTOS</a>
```

The VLB galleries retain their stock IDs of "vlightbox1", "vlightbox2", etc.

Obviously, I can't override the "bigbutton" class or the button won't display properly.  Similarly, I have tried linking the "bigbutton" class to the lightbox trigger, but I'm obviously writing something wrong.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just grab the anchor and attach a handler to the click event?

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("bigbutton");
for(var i=0;i<btns.length;i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", (function(e){

        // .. do trigger code here

    }), false); // this only handles W3C due to addEventListener
}
```

Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "override the 'bitbutton' class", but you can have multiple classes on the element.

```
<a href="album-detail.html" class="bigbutton mysecond_class">VIEW PHOTOS</a>
```

================== EDIT =======================

Looking at the code from the site, it seems like you need to change the href of your link, as well as the textnode. In the end, the code should look something like this:

```
<div id='vlightbox1'>
    <a href='path/to/my/image1.jpg' class='vlightbox1 bigbutton' title='my title'>
      <img src='path/to/my/image1.jpg' />
    </a>
    <a href='path/to/my/image2.jpg' class='vlightbox1 bigbutton' title='my second title'>
      <img src='path/to/my/image2.jpg' />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay in replying - just got back to the laptop.  So, I'm normally pretty good at all this for someone without formal training in the subject matter.  But I have to admit that you've thrown a new one at me.  Of all the solutions I've run across in researching this technique, the code you've written is brand new to me.  Can you provide a bit of detail on it?  In the meantime, I'm going to try it the way I think you mean for it to work and I'll update with a result as soon as I can....Thanks, again!

Comment: Okay, so adding a second class by itself does nothing.  I.E.: <a class="vlightbox1 bigbutton" href="data/images1/11.jpg">VIEW ALBUM</a> does not call the Visual Lightbox.  Interestingly, though, it does trigger a funky loading overlay on the button, itself, but not the lightbox.  So what am I missing?  :(

Comment: Okay, a little explanation of the code given: btns is an array of all the elements with a class of "bigbutton", then I'm looping through that array and individually attaching an event handler to each element in the array. When someone clicks on any of the elements that are contained in that array, the function where it says `// .. do trigger code` will be ran. the false just means that the event won't bubble. Mozilla Developer Network would have some good info on it.

Comment: As for the second class thing, can you provide a link to a page where it behaves the way you described? I've never worked with the library you're using, but I would doubt it's too different from other libraries that I have used. From the site, it looks like the href should be the path to an image. However, it looks like you're trying to link to a page.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear on the href in my first post.  Because I started this project with a template, there is a lot of stuff that I'm hacking up to better fit the final project.  So the href in the original template code is what I posted above and was wondering how it should read in conjunction with the code that I'm trying to employ on that CSS button.  The thumbnails that actually work so far bear the link of <a class="vlightbox1" href="data/images1/11.jpg" title=""><img src="data/thumbnails1/11.jpg" alt=""/></a> .  I just want to do THIS action with my CSS button.  Ugh.